Civ 6: View gold breakdown in PS5
I'm used to playing civilization in the PC, and I can easily see a breakdown of all my sources of gold and expenses by mousing over the gold balance at the top of the screen.
I just started playing the same game in the Playstation 5.
How to view the same gold breakdown?

A user called Guarnerian on the bottom of a Gamefaqs page said,

You can check yields by pressing R1, its the 2nd from the bottom

Above that, another user called Gigant0pithecus said,

For some stuff on-screen you can press the touchpad and have it cycle through the tool-tips, similar to hovering your arrow over it using m&k. Seems to only work for certain things, though.


Checking yields worked well enough.  At the bottom there's the international agreement money,  which is what I wanted.
